# Código mal formado

Tags: wordpress

Trabajando en un escenario WordPress, no se ven errores en la consola y todo funciona con normalidad. En un post type concreto al añadir una entrada, siempre que la guardo una parte del código se va siempre de viaje. Siempre afecta a los `<h4>`. Curiosamente el cierre de la etiqueta lo pone donde quiere y ademas le añade la clase. Lógicamente esto rompe todo el renderizado normal.

¿Alguien se ha encontrado con algo asi?. En la entrada pego el código que previamente he escrito en Visual Studio.

Al pegar unos estilos en el editor de código de la entrada. se encuentran entre  ...

```
.accordian-wrapper.searched .accordian-element {<br />
  display: none;<br />
}<br />
.accordian-wrapper.searched .accordian-element.active {<br />
  display: inherit;<br />
}<br />
.found-term {<br />
  color: red;<br />
}</p>
```

[image: Código mal formado]

Comment: ¿Ese código es **antes** de pasar por el wordpress?  Lo digo porque la etiqueta de cierre del `</h4>` no se pone con la clase, sino tal cual.  Por cierto, el código [**nunca** como imagen](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2869#2869), sino será dificil ayudarte a no poderlo copiar/pegar para nuestras pruebas y podrian votarte negativamente por ello (mira el enlace que he puesto, alli lo explica mejor).

Comment: Lo de la clase sucede al guardar con WordPress. El código lo renderizo en mi navegador en local sin incidencias. Es una estructura bien simple. No se si se trata de algún problema propio del editor de bloques. No me permiten desactivarlo.

Comment: ¿Y no será algun plugin del wordpress que interfiere con eso?  Los hay que son muy malos y presuponen demasiadas cosas o no todas ellas, y luego lo estropean todo o impiden segun que cosas.  Si tienes plugins raros que puedan interferir prueba deshabilitar algunos mientras editas a ver que pasa.

Comment: Si, realmente ya he pensado en esa opción. Voy a esperar a que sea bien tarde para que nadie se queje. No hay entorno staging para hacer pruebas y depurar con tranquilidad.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner la entrada que dices que pegas desde Visual Studio correspondiente a esa captura en la pregunta en modo texto?  Lo digo porque tampoco entiendo el porque lo encierras entre guiones y no se si tambien los pone el WP o eres tu.

Comment: Debe haber algun error en el loop, desde el fronted no te podemos ayudar, mejor postea el codigo del single y archive.php

Comment: ¿Qué significa *una parte del código se va siempre de viaje*? Lo que se puede ver en la imagen que estás compartiendo, como bien ha señalado @masterguru es que la clase se está agregando también al cerrar el elemento `h4`, lo cual es incorrecto. Eso puede venir de un plugin, o de código personalizado que hayas programado (en  `functions.php` o reglas CSS) o de un hook, o un shortcode o quién sabe. Sin estar en tu contexto es difícil para nosotros poder saberlo...

Comment: ... Wordpress tiene un modo de debug que podrías activar: `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );` No muestra mensajes en pantalla, sino que escribe los logs en un archivo y puedes examinar ese archivo en busca de respuesta a tu problema. OJO, cuando hayas resuelto el problema apaga esa opción, pues si no creará archivos enorrrrmes en tu servidor. Para más detalles, consulta [este post](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) donde se explica cómo activarlo, en qué archivo se guardan los logs, etc.

Comment: Con lo de que se va de viaje me refiero que traslada el cierre de <h4> a un lugar sin sentido, además de repetir la clase en ese fragmento, cosa que tiene menos sentido. Gracias de todas formas

Comment: Entiendo. La mejor manera de saber lo que pasa es [activando el log de debug](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/#wp_debug_log). Cuando lo actives, abre uno de los posts que presentan ese problema y luego revisa el archivo que se creará en la ruta: `wp-content/debug.log`. Allí verás quizá advertencias o noticias sobre lo que está ocurriendo en el proceso de creación de tu post.

Comment: en el code pegado `.accordian-wrapper.searched .accordian-element {<br />` el `<br/>` aparece en el source del html ? ( ctrl+u ) si es así es que el css está siendo "fomateado" por el filtro `content` y dependiendo de como y donde se inserte el navegador va a intentar cerrar las etiquetas al mostrarlo ( sobre todo el `/p` )